# 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression.' in selecting data between two dates

Tags: c#

I'm trying to select data between two dates but im still getting 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression.' error. How to solve this?

```
        string startdate;
        string enddate;

        startdate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        enddate = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");


        int i = 0;
        OleDbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from Sales where Date>='"+ startdate.ToString() +"' AND Date<='"+ enddate.ToString() +"'";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {

            i = i + Convert.ToInt32(dr["Total"].ToString());

        }

        txttotalsales.Text = i.ToString();
```

Comment: You should be using parameterized queries instead of hand crafted query

Comment: In which line the error thrown? Also avoid using string concatenation for values in SQL query, it's prone to SQL injection. Use parameters instead.

Comment: the error is thrown at the ExecuteNonQuery part

Comment: Can you check the DateTime format in Table Column vs the startDate.ToString(). May be you need to format the date when forming query. Or Better use Param'd query.

Comment: What database are you using? Whats the date format? UTC or Unix timestamp?